# Find in path with word boundary by default

Tags: intellij-idea

Regarding IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2

Select a piece of text, then do a find in path(`Ctrl+Shift+F`). By default I want it to do a Regex search limited by word boundaries([`\b`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html)), i.e.:

```
table
```

Should become:

```
\btable\b
```

Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Isn't there a `[ ] Words` check in that very same dialog that you can just check and leave enabled?

Comment: @LuisG. Wow, how didn't I notice this? Will try it.